# Inmovilizar celdas de excel con php

Tags: php, mvc, cakephp, phpexcel

Hola estoy usando esta libreria

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

y quiero inmovilizar la fila superior así como se ve en el video:

https://computerhoy.com/video/como-mantener-siempre-visible-encabezado-columna-excel-32981

en la version anterior de phpExcel lo hacia así pero en esta version no he encontrado como :
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,4);

Comment: según creo recordar en la nueva versión los índices empiezan en 1, prueba `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(1,4);` ó `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePaneByColumnAndRow("A4");`

Comment: @aloMalbarez thanks, si me sirvio pero aun tengo una pregunta, sabes como eliminar las lineas de division pero no a todo el archivo sino a una region especifica?

Comment: los bordes de celda?

Comment: @aloMalbarez si

Comment: Pienso que se podria eliminar toda la division y luego agregarle estilo de bordes a las que necesito, pero no se como eliminar toda la division

Comment: Líneas de división*